# Processing file(s) and folders via drag and drop, filtering file types

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script that can take any of the following three inputs:

-drag and drop a folder
-drag and drop a single file
-drag and drop a selection of multiple files

and perform a cmd command (transcoding some video with VLC) on all the files so presented that match a list of file types.  I've tried doing this a number of different ways, but each way seems to have a showstopping shortcoming of one kind or another.

I can get the script to check for VLC being installed, determine whether it's been given a file, files, or folder, and process an individual file just fine without filtering extensions; it's processing multiple files, processing a folder, and filtering by extension that are tripping me up:

```
@echo off
Title PPT Transcoder
Mode con cols=120 lines=16
IF [%~1] == "" GoTo :Error_ranDirectly
IF exist "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" (
    CD /D "%~1">nul 2>&1 && Goto :Explorer_Folder || Goto :Files
) else (
    Goto :Error_VLCNotInstalled
)
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
:Files <File>
Color 0E
ECHO    Transcoding %1 to %1_PPT.mp4... 

REM I really want to filter for six filetypes here (.mp4, .avi, .mov., .wmv,
REM .flv, .gif) and not affect any others. Forfiles looks like it could 
REM work, but I can't figure out how to get it to work on my arguments 
REM rather than the entire folder of files that match the filter.

"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" [a bunch of flags] %1 [a bunch more flags]:file{dst=%1_PPT.mp4,no-overwrite} [even more flags] vlc://quit
IF [%~2] == "" Goto :FilesFinished
shift 
GoTo :Files
:FilesFinished
Color 0A
Echo Finished processing.
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak >nul
Exit /b

::**********************************************************
:Explorer_Folder <Folder>
REM This block of code almost works, but i think it malforms the file names 
REM fed to vlc.  It runs and thinks it's working, but fails to actually 
REM accomplish anything.

setlocal
Color 0C
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Transcode all files in folder %1 (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO :Abort
Color 0F
for %%x in (%1\*.mp4 %1\*.mov %1\*.avi %1\*.wmv %1\*.flv) do (
echo Transcoding %%x to %%x_PPT.mp4... 
""C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" [a bunch of flags] %%x [a bunch more flags]:file{dst=%%x_PPT.mp4,no-overwrite} [even more flags] vlc://quit
echo Done.)
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak >nul
endlocal
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
:Error_RanDirectly
Color 0C & echo(
ECHO    Drag and drop video files on the icon to transcode them. 
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak >nul
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
:Error_VLCNotInstalled
Color 0C & echo(
ECHO    VLC 64-bit (free download from videolan.org) must be installed.
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak >nul
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
:Abort
Exit /b
```

I guess to make this a general question: Is there a generally accepted framework for making a batch script handle drag and drop execution intelligently?

Comment: This will never be true `IF [%~1] == "" ` use `if "%~1"==""`

Comment: Thanks!  Any insight into my main question?

Comment: Clue: `if exist somefile.ext\\` always fails if somefile.ext is not a directory. In other words, you can just process all the parameter strings passed into the script to decide whether it's a directory string, by appending a backslash to it and checking if it exists.

Comment: @jwdonahue
`@if exist "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" echo it exists!`

Seems to work fine.  I only use exists to check whetehr VLC is installed.

My actual questions are
a) How to do a secondary check for file type when processing individual files,   
b) How to process a bunch of arguments so that dragging multiple files works, and  
c) How to process a folder, filtering filetypes

Comment: By file type, do you mean its extension?

Comment: If you want to classify file types, first you have to determine if it's a directory, if not, use the file extension as the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this as a cmd file and drop directories and files on it.  See how it works.

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@rem @set prompt=$G

@call :ShowTypes %*
@pause
@exit /b

:ShowTypes
@echo Processing:
:_showTypes
@rem If it exists with a slash appended to the end, 
@rem it's directory, otherwise a file type.
@if exist "%1\\" (@set _type=directory) else (@call :SetFileType "%1")
@if "%1" neq "" (echo %1 as %_type%) else (exit /b 0)
@shift
@goto :_showTypes

:SetFileType
@rem %~x1 is the extension of the first parameter passed by caller.
@set _type=%~x1
@rem Remove the dot from the extension string.
@set _type=%_type:.=%
@rem Now _type is whatever the extension was.
@exit /b 0
```

Remove the leading `@` symbol to see that line in action.

Comment: `CD /D "%~1">nul 2>&1 && Goto :Folder || Goto :File` works for differentiating files from directories, but that code is helpful in understanding how strings, variables, and pathnames can interact in batch scripts.

Comment: The problem with changing directories is that it will succeed in changing directories when the string contains a valid path.