# Drag and drop files and folders into command batch

Tags: batch-file

So here's the last code i've done with your help.

```
@echo off
Title ..::RoboCoveriZer: Auto add covers to your MKV::..
Mode con cols=81 lines=9
IF "%~1"=="" Goto:Error
set mkvpredt=mkvpropedit.exe
pushd "%~1"
for %%I in ("*.mkv") DO (
"%mkvpredt%" "%%~nxI" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg" --add-attachment "%%~nI.jpg"
)
pause
exit
```

Is there any way to open the command window and make it wait for drag and drop on it to start the process?

Comment: Don't use `[]`. [Use quotes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48282847/2152082)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing file(s) and folders via drag and drop, filtering file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222020/processing-files-and-folders-via-drag-and-drop-filtering-file-types)

Comment: @Stephan is correct. Replace:  
  
    `IF [%1] EQU [] Goto:Error`
  
With:  
  
    `IF "%1"=="" Goto :Error`

Comment: You have `IF "%1"` and `pushd "%~1"`. The inconsistency with handling the 1st argument makes possible that either `"%1"` or `"%~1"` may fail. If the argument is quoted and you add quotes, then quote pairing may change. I would use `"%~1"` as it strips the quotes and adds the quotes thus is the same quoting as the original argument.

Comment: @michael_heath you mean like this? IF "%~1" ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain why in my last comment. Regarding your question post, too many varying questions make it too broad. I doubt anyone will answer based on this. Posts are versioned so no need for "*edit:*" or "*update:*" etc. Improvement of the post may improve chances of an acceptable answer.

Comment: @michael_heath thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
title ..::RoboCoveriZer: Auto add covers to your MKV::..
mode con cols=81 lines=9

set "mkvpredt=mkvpropedit.exe"

:: Get all arguments.
set input=%*

:: Get input path(s) if needed.
if not defined input set /p "input=Enter MKV path(s): "

:: Exit if no input.
if not defined input exit /b

:: Display each argument (optional code).
if defined input for %%A in (%input%) do echo input: %%A

:: Call each argument which can be a file or folder.
for %%A in (%input%) do call :step_1 "%%~A"

pause
exit /b


:step_1
:: Process a folder of MKV files or a single file.

:: Call each MKV file if pushd succeeds.
2>nul pushd "%~1" && (
    for %%A in (*.mkv) do call :step_2 "%%~A"
    popd
    exit /b
)

:: Exit if not MKV file.
if /i not "%~x1" == ".mkv" exit /b 1

:: Call single MKV file.
call :step_2 "%~1"
exit /b


:step_2
:: Coverize MKV file.
echo "%mkvpredt%" "%~f1"^
 --attachment-name "cover"^
 --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg"^
 --add-attachment "%~dpn1.jpg"
exit /b
```

Drag'n'drop on a file is handled by `%*`.
Command line arguments are handled by `%*`.
If `%*` is assigned to a variable named `input`
and if `input` is not defined, then use `set /p`
to get input from the user. The user can
drag'n'drop or type a file or folder on to
the window to satisfy `set /p` and press
<kbd>return</kbd> to continue.

The code provided can handle the actions
mentioned and can process file and folder
paths.

The first `for` loop passes each argument
to `call :step_1`. This can be a file or
folder path which can include wildcard
patterns.

Label `:step_1` tries `pushd` on the argument
passed and if succeeds, loops through
`*.mkv` and calls the label `:step_2` with
each file as argument. If pushd fails, treat
it as a single file and `call :step_2` with
the file as argument.

`:step_2` does the coverize if the `echo`
is removed.